# Installing and using VNC for command-line purposes on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, vnc

I am running a VPS with FreeBSD 8.3-RELEASE-p3

I locked myself out of su by taking my user out of wheel group.

I have disabled the ability to login with 'root' from SSH in order to increase the security level of my server.

I know that someVPS providers provide remote console control service that allows you to see what's going on the screen while booting and everything, but mine doesn't allow that.

Will installing VNC for command-line use only, keep me unworried of making mistakes like
taking myself out of 'wheel' and not being able to 'su'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not root, you will not be able to install VNC, so this will not help.

I think there are only two options

1. Tell your Provider to log into the system from the console and readd the user to wheel.
2. Find and exploit to enhance your privileges.  :)

Comment: I didn't explain myself well, I am root, I can install w/e I want.

Comment: if you are root you can just readd your user to the wheel group

Comment: but I don't have physical access to the box, so if I take myself out of wheel group - I'm locked out. (I've disabled the ability to login with 'root' as username for security measures).

Comment: so basically you don't have the possibility to execute an installation program as root.

Comment: why not? after logging in with my normal user, I use su (since I'm in wheel group I am able to do so...)

Comment: before you wrote that you removed yourself from the wheel group. Please decide in which groups you are

Comment: I have formatted and re-installed FBSD ever since...

Comment: if I've added 'next time' to the end of the question, would you understand me better?

Comment: tamam, Checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing#Security It seems the Encryption of VNC is not as good as ssh. So i would suggest to use something else as a fallback. For example a second SSHd with http://www.marksanborn.net/linux/add-port-knocking-to-ssh-for-extra-security/ or Google authenticator http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/